# Ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia 375.66, and GT Cards

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I am attempting to set up a display driving GPU along with a Tesla K40. If I use the current NVIDIA driver, 375.66, I get a black screen as my output on both VGA and HDMI for both the GT 520 and GT 610. If I downgrade the drivers to 340.102 (a driver I had on hand) the video output comes through fine. The problem here is that this driver isn't cudatoolkit 8.0 compatible though so I can't run any code. Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Comment: I had the same exact problem, so I uninstalled nvidia-375 and reinstalled the nvidia-340 driver in 16.04. I only tried to upgrade to nvidia-375 in order to also install nvidia-cuda-toolkit 7.5, so I had to uninstall nvidia-cuda-toolkit too.

Comment: I was messing around and the problem gets more annoying. After running apt-get nvidia-current, if I have my HDMI cable plugged into my motherboard and run of integrated my additional drivers shows both the GT 620 with the option to select between the 340 driver and X-server and it shows the Tesla k40 with X-Server and 375. If I plug my HDMI cable into the 620 the additional drivers page no longer shows the k40 and the 620 now can now pick between 375, 340, and X-server. If I select 375, the output from the 620 no longer works and I have to run nvidia-current for the k40 to show up again.

Comment: Have you tried either the 381 or 384 drivers? - https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa (unless you fall under  "For G8x, G9x and GT2xx GPUs use `nvidia-340`"

Comment: I haven't yet. I was going to give it a shot tomorrow.